# Different vue.config.js for npm run serve and npm run build

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

I'm overriding webpack config using vue.config.js:

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
  publicPath: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080',
  outputDir: './dist/',

  chainWebpack: config => {

    config.optimization
      .splitChunks(false)

    config
      .plugin('BundleTracker')
      .use(BundleTracker, [{ filename: './webpack-stats.json' }])

    config.resolve.alias
      .set('__STATIC__', 'static')

    config.devServer
      .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
      .host('0.0.0.0')
      .port(8080)
      .hotOnly(true)
      .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
      .https(false)
      .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] })
  }
};
```

The webpack-bundle-tracker plugin generates a file called webpack-stats.json:

```
{
  "status": "done",
  "publicPath": "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
  "chunks": {
    "app": [
      {
        "name": "app.js",
        "publicPath": "http://0.0.0.0:8080/app.js",
        "path": "/Users/me/dev/vue-app/dist/app.js"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My problem is that depending on whether I am in development or in production, I want the path to the file to be different.

- When I run `npm run serve`: the generated path should be `http://0.0.0.0:8080/app.js` (so that the file is served by npm and I can have hot reload etc.)
- When I run `npm run build`: the generated path should be `http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/app.js` (so that django can serve the file. please note the port number 8000, not 8080)

So I'm wondering if there's a way for vue.config.js to have 2 versions, one that would be used by `serve` the other one by `build`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is like two years old.
Use the absolute path for the environment variable VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH.
You could use $PWD to instead current absolute path.

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "serve:test": "env VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH=\"/var/www/html/your_project/vue.config_serve_test.js\" vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
```

npm run serve:test will use vue.config_serve_test.js

npm run build will use vue.config.js